# Proving $(X \triangle Z) \backslash (Y \triangle Z) \subseteq (X \backslash Y) \triangle Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove $(X \triangle Z) \backslash (Y \triangle Z) \subseteq (X \backslash Y) \triangle Z$?

I have tried looking what means $x \in (X \triangle Z) \backslash (Y \triangle Z),$ but I got to a point where it's so confusing that I gave up.

Is there a simple way to prove this?

Comment: Are you familiar with Venn diagrams? This might give you an intuition on what $X\Delta Z$ is. Do you know set notation? For instance, $X \setminus Y = \{x : x \in X \cap Y^c\}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just careful set operation.

By definition, $X \triangle Y = (X \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus X)=(X \cup Y) \setminus (X \cap Y)$.

Then we can show $Z \setminus (X \setminus Y)=(Z \cap Y) \cup (Z\setminus X)$ and $(Y \triangle Z)^c= (Y^c \cap Z^c) \cup (Y \cap Z)$, where $Y^c$ means complement of Y.

RHS $  =(X \backslash Y) \triangle Z = \Big((X \setminus Y) \setminus Z\Big) \cup (Z\cap Y) \cup (Z \setminus X)$.

LHS $=(X \triangle Z) \backslash (Y \triangle Z)=\Big((X \setminus Z) \cup (Z \setminus X) \Big) \cap \Big(((Y^c \cap Z^c) \cup (Y \cap Z)\Big)$

Let $A=(Z\cap Y) \cup (Z \setminus X)$

Then LHS $\subseteq\Big((X \setminus Z) \cup A \Big) \cap \Big(((Y^c \setminus Z) \cup A \Big)=\Big((X \setminus Y) \setminus Z\Big) \cup A=$RHS.

Hope this helps.